# Connect to TFS GIT domain\username + password

Tags: git, tfs

I'm trying to clone a TFS GIT repository into a linux redhat machine.

```
git clone myTFSGitURL
Username for 'https://tfs.domain.net': DOMAIN\myUSER
Password for 'https://DOMAIN\myUSER@tfs.domain.net':
```

I expected to be able to connect to the repository, but I get the error:

```
fatal: Authentication failed for myTFSGitURL
```

I believe that the domain is the issue as it looks weird that it states

```
Password for 'https://DOMAIN\myUSER@tfs.domain.net':
```

Comment: Did you try specifying the domain as @? E.g. `user@DOMAIN`?

Comment: Sorry, DOMAIN in capital letters refers to network domain, not to URL domain.

Comment: I know. Try it.

Comment: fatal: Authentication failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [use SSH key authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate) to clone git repo.

You can refer to this case: [git clone from Linux to TFS git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414232/git-clone-from-linux-to-tfs-git-repo)

Comment: Did the steps to create a ssh key pair, included the public key in TFS security configuration, now facing the following error:

Connection open failed; Key exchange failed (local): MAC (client to server) negotiation failed. Client algorithms are hmac-sha1,hmac-sha256@ssh.com,hmac-sha384@ssh.com,hmac-sha512@ssh.com, server hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: It seems there is a no matching MAC algorithem issue, please check the link https://blog.tinned-software.net/debug-ssh-connection-issue-in-key-exchange/ to see whether it helps you. Meanwhile, you could open a new case on SSH tag to see whether there is more help.