# Accessing TFS code from Docker

Tags: windows, git, docker, tfs

I have a docker running on my local Windows box and I need to clone the code from our TFS server using Git.

Docker is using linode/lamp (debian). Running `# git clone http://our_server/tfs/The_Project`
I get

`Cloning into The_Project ...
Username for http://our_server: xxxxx
Password for http://our_server: 
fatal: Authentication failed for http://our_server/tfs/The_Project`

Comment: Can you ping ourserver? Do you have any special character in your password?

Comment: Are you sure of the repository URL? It seems to me that it should contains '_git' somewhere inside...

Comment: Can you try use SSH?

Comment: @VonC yes I could ping it

Comment: @Philippe the url up in the question is an example but the actual one does have _git in it

Comment: How are you authenticating within your Docker container? You probably need to supply a PAT or some other form of alternate authentication.

Comment: @DanielMann just like what I'm doing on my local machine by providing username and password when I get prompted

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like a docker issue but just a case of [git clone from Linux to TFS git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47414232/git-clone-from-linux-to-tfs-git-repo): you can look there for an answer.

TFS requires Windows Authentication so your options are:

1. change TFS configuration to allow Basic Authentication
2. change TFS configuration to allow SSH
3. install [Git Credential Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/set-up-credential-managers) for the OS in the container